# A problem from book Euclid and beyond

Tags: geometry

$D$ is between $A$ and $E , B$ is between $A$ and $C$.

Prove that segment $EB$ and segment $DC$ intersect at a point $M$.(Using axiom of incidence and axiom of betweeness)

Comment: You should probably add that $E$, $A$ and $C$ are not aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact wording of the axioms in Hartshorne's book, but the proof will be at most a minor variation on what follows.

Segment AD doesn't meet line BE, since line AD does meet line BE, but at E, which is not in segment AD. Therefore A and D are on the same side of line BE.

Segment AC does meet line BE, at B. Therefore A and C are on opposite sides of BE.

Putting the last two facts together, D and C are on opposite sides of line BE. Therefore segment CD meets line BE at some point M.

Exchanging the roles of B, C and D, E, we similarly find that segment BE meets line CD at some point N.

Since lines BE and CD can meet in only one point, we actually have N = M. Segments BE and CD meet at M.